# How to get the position of a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a parent div in my dom hierarchy and around 100 sub elements inside the parent div. I've binded a click event on each sub element. what I want is the position of sub element from the top of the parent element. I used jquery `.position` nd `.offset` but both return the position from the top of the page. The parent div is scrollable which means the offlow is hidden. so subtracting top position from the position of the clicked element is not going to work! Can anyone suggest me a work around for this!

Comment: Set `relative` to the parent block and use `.position()`.

Comment: you want exact pixel positions or just the base positions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `position: relative;` style to the parent element:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px;" id="clicker">Click Me</div>    
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#clicker").click(function() {
        var $clicker = $(this);
        var pos = $clicker.position();
       console.log(pos.top);
        console.log(pos.left);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LaEsw/

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri it would be better if you posted sample HTML.

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri I added an example fiddle

Comment: This works! sorry I said it didn't work earlier. I used offset and checked first. Then I tried position and it worked! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

`.offset()` returns the position relative to the document, while `.position()` returns the position relative to the offset parent. `.position()` would be what you want here, but you need the parent to be "positioned" (having a `position` other than `static`, like `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute`). Otherwise, the nearest positioned parent would be the document itself and `.position()` will act like `.offset()`

Add `position:relative` to the parent you want to base the position of your element.